# Facebook API full_picture is cropped, how to get a non-cropped version?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the [Facebook API Graph Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/1) and trying to retrieve a full size image that is larger than 720 it gets cropped to a square.

This is the image for use in the Facebook graph API tool using version v2.12:

```
127495184638742_166955060692754?fields=full_picture,picture,link
```

How can I get back a full version of the image? Scaled is ok, just need the full image.

The docs that reference 'full_picture' are here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/post

They say:

> URL to a full-sized version of the Photo published in the Post or scraped from a link in the Post. If the photo's largest dimension exceeds 720 pixels, it will be resized, with the largest dimension set to 720.

But do not outline how to change the square cropping that is being applied.

[the cropped version of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlLuR.png)
[image: The original version of the image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an 'event' type, then you can get the full image if you take the `object_id` and use it in a separate facebook call to:

```
(object_id)?fields=cover,place,start_time,end_time
```

and the `cover` url will contain the full image.

Answer (score 0):

Hit **photo_id/?fields=images** in graph api. This will return a set of different size images. Use the high resolution one.

For full reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/